# Binomial distribution problem

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, contingency-tables

What is the probability that 4 out of 181 and 55 out of 181 belong to the same distribution? Which distribution will give the best fit?

Assume you have, say, a manufacturing process from which you draw 181 samples. The percentage of failures is not known. If you get 4 failures out of the 181 samples at one time and 55 failures at another time, what is the probability that the process has not changed, i.e. it produces the same percentage of failures?

Comment: How do you define "belonging to the same distribution"?

Comment: Assume you have, say, a manufacturing process from which you draw 181 samples. The percentage of failures is not known. If you get 4 failures out of the 181 samples at one time and 55 failures at another time, what is the probability that the process has not changed, i.e. it produces the same percentage of failures?

Comment: Please edit your question to add those details, it seems that you are asking about some kind of anomaly detection. The mo0re details you give us, the more likely you are to get a valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can present your data as a contingency table:

```
          A   B
fail      4  55
success 177 126
```

and then use a chisquare test:

```
    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  mytab
X-squared = 50.624, df = 1, p-value = 1.119e-12
```

and the conclusion should be clear.